# Incompatible types found java.lang : ArrayAdapter

Tags: java, android, android-arrayadapter

when I try below line of code

```
ItemRow itemdata = data.get(position);
```

in ItemAdapter class I got the error

Incompatible types required: com.fragment.ItemRow found: java.lang.object

the complete ItemRow.java class is as below:

```
Package com.fragments;

import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;

public class ItemRow {

String itemName;
Drawable icon;

public ItemRow(String itemName, Drawable icon) {
    super();
    this.itemName = itemName;
    this.icon = icon;
}

public String getItemName() {
    return itemName;
}
public void setItemName(String itemName) {
    this.itemName = itemName;
}
public Drawable getIcon() {
    return icon;
}
public void setIcon(Drawable icon) {
    this.icon = icon;
}

}
```

and the complete Itemadapeter class in which I got the incompatible type when I try

-ItemRow itemdata = data.get(position); in getView

```
package com.fragments;
public class ItemAdapter extends ArrayAdapter {

List   data;
Context context;
int layoutResID;

public ItemAdapter(Context context, int layoutResourceId,List data) {
    super(context, layoutResourceId, data);

    this.data=data;
    this.context=context;
    this.layoutResID=layoutResourceId;

    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
 }

  @Override
  public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    NewsHolder holder = null;
    View row = convertView;
    holder = null;

    if(row == null)
    {
        LayoutInflater inflater = ((Activity)context).getLayoutInflater();
        row = inflater.inflate(layoutResID, parent, false);

        holder = new NewsHolder();

        holder.itemName = (TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.example_itemname);
        holder.icon=(ImageView)row.findViewById(R.id.example_image);
        holder.button1=(Button)row.findViewById(R.id.swipe_button1);
        holder.button2=(Button)row.findViewById(R.id.swipe_button2);
        holder.button3=(Button)row.findViewById(R.id.swipe_button3);
        row.setTag(holder);
    }
    else
    {
        holder = (NewsHolder)row.getTag();
    }

    ItemRow itemdata = data.get(position);


    holder.itemName.setText(itemdata.getItemName());
    holder.icon.setImageDrawable(itemdata.getIcon());

    holder.button1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Toast.makeText(context, "Button 1 Clicked",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });

    holder.button2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Toast.makeText(context, "Button 2 Clicked",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });

    holder.button3.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Toast.makeText(context, "Button 3 Clicked",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
        }
    });

    return row;

}

static class NewsHolder{

    TextView itemName;
    ImageView icon;
    Button button1;
    Button button2;
    Button button3;
}

}
```

Comment: raw List   data; **why?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your list is `raw type` mean `Object` so you have to down-cast the `Object` to your POJO i.e `ItemRow`

```
ItemRow itemdata = (ItemRow )data.get(position);
```

or you should have a list of `List<ItemRow>` type , since there is no idea which kind of list you are passing to this adapter so make sure you pass the same type as `List<ItemRow>` in this case plus to follow best practice , mention the type with adapter as `extends ArrayAdapter<ItemRow>` and make the required changes at other places.

Answer (score 1):

Please use `List<ItemRow>` instead of `List`.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is caused by the following assignment in your `ItemAdapter`

```
List data;
```

Instead, try this

```
ArrayList<ItemRow> data;
```